# How to extend jumbotron to end of page

Tags: html, css

I have created a webpage and put most of the content into a jumbotron. At first the bottom navbar was covering all the content on the page and I thought that is why the background color wasn't showing, once I got that fixed I realized that the jumbotron is also not extending to the bottom navbar. I am ending up with a thin strip of the background color at the top of the page, but it doesn't extend behind the content that is inside the jumbotron unless you minimize the web browser. When it is a smaller screen it extends. I would like the background color to extend the length of the page when it is full size, without being throughout the entire body. Is there a way to fix this with the jumbotron, or is there a better way to go about it?

I have tried changing the height of the jumbotron. I have also adjusted the padding which helped a little bit, but either creates a lot of empty space after the content or doesn't quite cover all the content on the page (depending on the size of the screen).

html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="about"><img src="About.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="introduction">
        Welcome to my business page! I am so glad that you found me. <br><br>I am a daughter of the King, a wife to this wonderful guy , a mother of two, and a lover of photography! <br><br>I began my photography journey in May of 2019 when my husband bought me a DSLR camera for mother’s day. I always enjoyed photography, but hadn’t been able to pursue it because I didn’t have a camera. When I was given my first camera I absolutely fell in love with the entire process. <br><br>Since deciding to turn my photography into a career I have chosen to become the best photographer that I can be. I am currently taking classes at an online school to obtain my Bachelor’s Degree in Digital Photography. I am always looking to improve my photography and provide the best portraits possible to my clients. <br><br>I really enjoy what I do and I am so glad that it allows me the freedom to control my schedule. I can plan my days around my kids and still help to support my family. <br><br>My passion is capturing your precious moments and helping you remember the best times in your life. Please reach out to me to make your portrait dreams a reality.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  background-color: #ffeaea;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: initial;
  height: 100%;
}
.introduction {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
```

Perhaps there is something that is wrong that I am not seeing.

Comment: Try this <div class="jumbotron" style="height:100vh;"></div>

Comment: That helped a little bit but only extended the color about halfway down the page...